# Mongo aggregate broken in creation of collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var emails = getAllEmails();
SurveyDL.aggregate([
      { $match: { email: { $in: emails } } },
      { $out: listMatchColl }
    ], function(err, data) {
        if (err) return console.log('Aggregate err:', err);
       }
 );
```

I have an `emails` arrays with numbers of emails. Above code work fine if `emails` array length will approx 400000 but when it length will be approx 900000 then it throw an error i.e,

> Unhandled rejection MongoError: attempt to write outside buffer bounds
>       at Buffer.write (buffer.js:605:11)
>       at serializeString (/home/vivek/nrich/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:33:37)
>       at serializeInto (/home/vivek/nrich/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:535:17)
>       at serializeObject (/home/vivek/nrich/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:280:18)

Comment: you're probably running into https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#memory-restrictions

Comment: thanks @Astro for reply. After update my code it look  `SurveyDL.aggregate([{ $match: { email: { $in: emails } } }, { $out: listMatchColl }], { allowDiskUse: true }, function(err, data) { if (err) return console.log('err', err); }); }` but i still have error i.e, Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Comment: try this:                                                                             SurveyD.aggregate([{ $match: { email: { $in: emails } } }, { $out:listMatchColl }], { allowDiskUse: true },function(err,data){if(err){return console.log("error". err); }} )